# Samsung SCX 4321 scanner not recognizing

Tags: scanner, samsung

Ubuntu Version 19.10
I have installed the UID drivers for both scanner and Printer. Printer is working, but the scanner is not recognizing.
Everytime I try to scan using Sane,it shows the message: You need to download more drivers
How do I make it work.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did for a Samsung scanner under 18.04. Worked for me - but unsure whether it will still work under 19.xx.

Samsung scanner driver is not packaged as part of Ubuntu 18.04. Driver is required for scanner to be available to scanning applications (e.g. Simple Scan). Some kind folks did re-package the Samsung driver. Sounds good so far.

BUT: Driver is unmaintained & may fail under re-worked Ubuntu 19.xx printer subsystem.

1. Download driver hosted here: https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suld.html
2. Extract archive
3. Open console & navigate to root of extracted folder
4. Run:

```
    sudo ./install-scanner.sh
```

5. Page through & accept EULA. Should see messages like:

```
    **** Registering SANE backend …
    **** Restarting udev …
    **** Scan driver has been installed successfully.
    **** Install finished.
```

Should now be able to run SimpleScan with Samsung CLX-3300.

Not tried under 19.xx. Hope this helps.